# vim latex livereload/preview plugin

Tags: filetype-tex

Can you please suggest any `latex` plugin with livereload/preview support ? All of the plugins google suggested me does not support preview/reload, or use 3rd party tools that use another 3rd party tools and so on... Which one do you use or can suggest (if you sure it really work on linux).

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)? I am not sure I quite understand what you mean by "livereload". `vimtex` supports previewing with different viewers and uses `latexmk` as a backend for continuous compilation. It works well on Linux.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The most common output of `LaTeX` nowadays is a pdf file, that must be viewed in a pdf viewer, and any decent pdf viewer will automatically refresh when the file displayed changes. If you mean "auto-compile every so often", I don't think this a good "feature" at all, as an "auto-compilation" might happen at a point when the `LaTeX` source is "broken".

Comment: Currenty , i use `pdflatex` for compiling my `.tex` files into `.pdf` and then open it with `zathura` pdf viewer. I would see my documents after i change something without running additional commands manually or even waste time to save changes inside the editor. How do you resolve it ? It seems like i can map some keys for building. I thought there is complete solution for case like mine.

Comment: If you don't save the file, all the changes are just on the vim buffer. What would it trigger on? `CursorMoveI`? You might wanna put a shebang at the top to tell the shell to open the file in `pdflatex` and then map something to `:w<cr>:!%:p<cr>` or something similar

Comment: I think, there have to be solution for previewing documents while editing... or not ?

Comment: Most people are content to save the file, and use `latexmk` with continuous compilation mode on; the pdf viewer will auto-refresh the pdf at every save, thus acting like a nice and easy preview method. Use git commits instead of using save as an "important work was done" operation.

Comment: Aha, interesting, what is "git commits operation" ?

Comment: @SvetlanaLinuxenko See for example: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/basics/basic-workflow#start

Comment: @VanLaser so ? How it could help me with compiling `tex` documents in vim ?

Comment: @SvetlanaLinuxenko It helps understanding that saving means a different thing when you can also commit to a repository.

Comment: hm.. @VanLaser, my question is about compiling/previewing documents while editing, without saving, i don't understand how git can help me wit it.

Comment: Because it's easier to preview *with* saving (last post here, just ignore everything if it doesn't make sense to you)

Comment: @VanLaser i cannot understand how does `git` related to the problem am trying to solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created the function that compile `tex` files, and can be mapped to any key binding. As @Dalker said `pdf viewer will automatically refresh when the file displayed changes` , and it really do.  Am not exactly sure about `git` related stuff @VanLaser said.. i think he meant that i have save the file changes first.. maybe not.. idk

```
function! MKTex()
  if (&ft == 'tex')
    let s:dir = expand('%:p:h')
    let s:file = expand('%:p')

    execute '!pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory ' . s:dir .' '. s:file
  else
    echo "For .tex files only."
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Just to add 2 points: 1) in the comments @ VanLaser was suggesting to automatically rebuilt your pdf each time you save your Vim buffer and to use an external tool (git) to save the important versions of your document. It could be useful to save the different steps of your work but this is not absolutely necessary in you case.

Comment: 2)  Now about your function: you could replace your whole function by this line: `autocmd FileType tex  command! -buffer MKTex execute '!pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory ' . expand('%:p:h') . ' ' . expand('%:p')` this way every time a buffer see its filetype set to `tex` the command `MKTex` will be defined only in this buffer its shorter and you don't have to check the filetype yourself. You can see [`:h :autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aautocmd) and [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd%2Devents)